# Dimension of tensors dont fit

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am replicating a pytorch model in keras and ahve problems to see where the extra dimension comes from.
This how my code looks so far:

```
class Attention(tf.keras.Model):
def __init__(self, input_shape):
    super(Attention, self).__init__()
    in_features=input_shape[-1]
    small_in_features = max(math.floor(in_features/10), 1)
    self.d_k = small_in_features

    query = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    query.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(in_features))
    query.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(small_in_features,activation="tanh"))
    self.query= query
    
    self.key = tf.keras.layers.Dense(small_in_features)

def call(self, inp):
    # inp.shape should be (B,N,C)
    q = self.query(inp)  # (B,N,C/10)
    k = self.key(inp)     # B,N,C/10
    k = tf.transpose(k)
    print(q)
    print(k)
    x = tf.linalg.matmul(q, k) / math.sqrt(self.d_k)  # B,N,N
    x = tf.nn.softmax(x)  # over rows
    x = tf.transpose(x)
    x = tf.linalg.matmul(x, inp)  # (B, N, C)
    return x
```

But if I want to add it to my Sequential model I get this Error:

```
 ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 1 and 256 for '{{node attention_19/MatMul}} = BatchMatMulV2[T=DT_FLOAT, adj_x=false, adj_y=false](attention_19/sequential_36/Identity, attention_19/transpose)' with input shapes: [?,256,1], [1,256,?].
```

I have now printed my 'q' and 'k' and it prints out like following:

```
Tensor("attention_19/sequential_36/Identity:0", shape=(None, 256, 1), dtype=float32)
Tensor("attention_19/transpose:0", shape=(1, 256, None), dtype=float32)
```

So they are 3 dimensional where one dimension is unfilled.I dont quite understand why it happens.

**How can I "remove" the extra dimension or bring this custom layer to work?**

Note: The original codes seems to use 3 dimensional Input but I want 2 dimensional input.

Comment: when you transpose k without arguments it flips the order of all dimensions. In your case, you need to keep None (batch_size) at the beginning, and transpose the rest. with k = tf.transpose(k, [0, 2, 1]). then tf.linalg.matmul(q, k) will return shape (None, N, N). Let me know if you still need changes.

Comment: You'll probably need to do the same for line x = tf.transpose(x) as well.

Comment: So B is the Batch_size and not an dimension to the input information? So it would be wise to keep the batch_size so I can vary it?

Comment: B is the batch size and by specifying None you ask tensorflow keras to compute it automatically from input so that it remains flexible (determined at input).

Comment: Be aware to always (unless specific code) keep batch_size dimension at beginning because usually all your calculations are performed per sample so that at the end your out is (None,....) where none refers to your flexible batch size.

Comment: Above q will be (None, 256, 1) and k.T is (None, 1, 256) and tf.linalg.matmul(q, k.T) will be of shape (None, 256, 256) by multiplying each line of q with every column of k.T in the batch.